# how to get the current chapter name, section name, subsection name, etc?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, mdframed

How can one get the current name of the following: Chapter, Section, Subsection(s), frame, label, mdframed?

Comment: What do you mean with `mdframed`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel mdframed's frametitle

Comment: You can use the option settings: `\mdfsetup{settings={\gdef\mdframetitlemark{\mdf@frametitle}}}`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

With this solution you can still use the starred versions and optional arguments of `\chapter` et al.

```
\documentclass{book}
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}
\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark
\def\sectionmark#1{\def\Sectionname{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}
\let\Subsubsectionmark\subsubsectionmark
\def\subsubsectionmark#1{\def\Subsubsectionname{#1}\Subsubsectionmark{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}\label{ch:first}
This is chapter~\ref{ch:first} with title ``\Chaptername''.
\section{First section}\label{sec:first}
This is section~\ref{sec:first} with title ``\Sectionname''.
\subsection{The first subsection}\label{subsec:first}
This is subsection~\ref{subsec:first} with title ``\Subsectionname''.
\subsubsection{Last subsubsection}\label{subsubsec:first}
This is subsubsection~\ref{subsubsec:first} with title ``\Subsubsectionname''.
\end{document}
```

Comment: very clever! +1

Comment: No, it [won't work with the starred versions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142982/36821).

Comment: @masu: it does work!

Comment: @Herbert: [I beg to differ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/143003/36821)... but maybe that was because of the magical ways of MikTeX, or we were mistaken somewhere.

Comment: remember that a starred version of `\section` et al are not part of the TOC and not listed in the header!

Comment: Didn't work for me for creating headers, until I used a `\def\Chaptername{}`and all that stuff, basically to initialize the empty macros.

Comment: @tifrel – If you only want to use `\chaptername` in page headers and footers, then [`\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) will define `\chaptertitle`, `\sectiontitle`, etc. that can be used when defining a page style.  Unfortunately, they're *only* available then, so this does not provide a general answer to this question.

Answer (score 32):

In terms of section titles, the [`nameref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) is ideal for this. It provides `\nameref{<label>}` that returns the sectional title associated with the label:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref
\begin{document}
\section{First section}\label{first}
This is section~\ref{first} with title \nameref{first}.
\subsection{Second subsection}\label{second}
This is subsection~\ref{second} with title \nameref{second}.
\subsubsection{Last subsubsection}\label{third}
This is subsubsection~\ref{third} with title \nameref{third}.
\end{document}
```

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides similar functionality, since it loads `nameref`. As such, they work together without problem, allowing hyperlinked titles. [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) does something similar to store the names/titles of sectional units.

This could be expanded to include the capture of names/titles associated with other environments or structures as well.

Comment: But I need the **current** section. With your labels I need to know the name already(essentially). i.e., you are just equating "first" with "first section", etc. Also, one has to specify the label each time. I could redefine section, subsection, chapter, etc but it seems like a lot of work.

Comment: e.g., `\newcommand{\currentchapter}{}` `\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\chapter{#1}\renewcommand{\currentchapter}{#1}}` and use `\mychapter` in place of `\chapter`

Comment: then `\currentchapter` contains the argument passed to the current `\mychapter`. I was hoping to avoid redefining or wrapping all the possible sectioning macros.

Comment: This approach still works, in 2021!

Answer (score 7):

Here is one solution but is not optimal. It simply renew's the old sectioning commands and have the new ones update the currentxxx macros.

```
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\currentchapter}{}
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\oldchapter{#1}\renewcommand{\currentchapter}{#1}}

\newcommand{\currentsection}{}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\oldsection{#1}\renewcommand{\currentsection}{#1}}

\newcommand{\currentsubsection}{}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\oldsubsection{#1}\renewcommand{\currentsubsection}{#1}}

\newcommand{\currentsubsubsection}{}
\let\oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{\oldsubsubsection{#1}\renewcommand{\currentsubsubsection}{#1}}


\chapter{chapter test}
\section{section test}
\subsection{subsection test}

\currentchapter\\
\currentsection\\
\currentsubsection\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the first thing that came to one's mind, but a problem arises when you want to use `\chapter*`

Comment: My dirty extension for the stared versions (requires `xparse` package) : `\newcommand{\currentchapter}{}\let\oldchapter\chapter\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{sm}{ \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\oldchapter*{#2}}{\oldchapter{#2} }\renewcommand{\currentchapter}{#1}}`

Comment: There is a small typo in the last part of my previous comment, it should be `\renewcommand{\currentchapter}{#2}`

Comment: The "dirty extension" gives me something useful, but for starred chapters like Index and References I get the name of the last chapter in the header. Would it be possible to include something to set the header to empty in a starred chapter? I played around a bit but couldn't find anything that works myself.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `\@sect` macro in `latex.ltx` for

```
%%%%
%%%%%%%
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
\xdef\sectionname{#8}% we change only here. 
%\xdef\leftmark{#8}
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
     \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
    \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
          \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
     \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
      #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}
%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Now, you can use `\sectionname` after calling `\section{....}`. For example, if `\section{Test}` is used, we get `\sectionname` expands to "Test".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, when inserting code, highlight the text to be formatted and then press the `{}` button.

Comment: This will, of course, not capture the chapter titles, nor be able to work in a true reference-like fashion where (title reference *before* section).

Answer (score 2):

[`titleref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleref) provides similar functionality to [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref), but is not compatible with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleref}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}\label{first}
This is section~\ref{first} with title \titleref{first}.
\subsection{Second subsection}\label{second}
This is subsection~\ref{second} with title \titleref{second}.
\subsubsection{Last subsubsection}\label{third}
This is subsubsection~\ref{third} with title \titleref{third}.
\end{document}
```