# References with section and subsection name?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I declare sections and subsections as such in my document:

```
\section{1}
\label{sec:1}

\subsection{a}
\label{sec:1a}
```

These are formatted using the *titlesec* package to display "Problem 1" and "Part a" respectively.

When I reference a given subsection using the `\ref{label}` command, it displays something like `1.1`, which are clearly the values of the section/subsection counters. What I want however, is **to display something like `1a` in references, where the`1` and the `a` respectively take their values from the section/subsection names**. I have tried using the *nameref* package to do this, but it only displays the `a` part, and there doesn't seem like a way to have the name of the section (containing the subsection) printed as well.

Any suggestions are welcome -- either in raw LaTeX, modifying `\nameref`, or using some other package.

Comment: This previous answer might be able to be adapter, incidentally: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62241/how-to-get-the-current-chapter-name-section-name-subsection-name-etc

Comment: If you name your `\section`s and `\subsection`s *exactly* like this, then using `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\alph{subsection}}` would yield `1a` for `\ref{sec:1a}`. However, since you're using a numbering scheme inside titles, it's best to use something else entirely that automates this. Otherwise you'll have to do a lot of work if you move stuff around.

Comment: @Werner: Indeed, I'd luck something a little more generic. Even if I decide to use that exact naming convention, the counters and titles could get out of sync too easily. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: Before answering, I have to say i think this is a really bad idea. If you don't want section titles, use `\section{}` etc. and configure the numbering scheme on the secion number side.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: I want the format "Problem 1/2/3" though, for titles of sections. And likewise "Part A/B/C" for subsections.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With my comment in mind, here's a patch for `\nameref` which will combine the names of two sectioning levels:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
\def\NR@gettitle#1{%
  \GetTitleString{#1}%
  \expandafter\let\csname @currentlabelname@\thesection@level\endcsname\GetTitleStringResult
  \edef\@currentlabelname
  {%
    \ifcsname
      @currentlabelname@\number\numexpr\c@section@level-\@ne\relax
    \endcsname
      \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {%
        \csname 
          @currentlabelname@\number\numexpr\c@section@level-\@ne\relax
        \endcsname
      }%
    \fi
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\GetTitleStringResult}%
  }
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{1}
\label{sec:1}

\subsection{a}
\label{sec:1a}

section: \nameref{sec:1}.

subsection: \nameref{sec:1a}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I hope it is clear that this is not very general, but it answers your exact question. It sould be possible to generalize it further.

### Edit

Patch when `titlesec` is used...

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\chapter@level{0}
\def\section@level{1}
\def\subsection@level{2}
\def\subsubsection@level{3}
\def\paragraph@level{4}
\def\subparagraph@level{5}

\patchcmd\ttl@straight@i{\def\@currentlabelname{#2}}
{%
  \expandafter\def
  \csname @currentlabelname@\csname#1@level\endcsname\endcsname{#2}%
  \edef\@currentlabelname
  {%
    \ifcsname
      @currentlabelname@\number\numexpr\csname#1@level\endcsname-\@ne\relax
    \endcsname
      \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {%
        \csname 
          @currentlabelname@\number\numexpr\csname#1@level\endcsname-\@ne\relax
        \endcsname
      }%
    \fi
    \unexpanded{#2}%
  }
}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: How odd. That still only prints `a` for me. :S

Comment: @Noldorin Remember to make two runs.

Comment: Yep, issue persists I'm afraid!

Comment: @Noldorin Interesting. Are you using the same document I posted, without alteration?

Comment: Nope it's in my own document... although I can't figure out why that should be any different. :/

Comment: It does indeed work in your demo document; I just tried that.

Comment: So it seems the *titlesec* package is interfering. Just the very declaration of `\usepackage{titlesec}` is the problem!

Comment: @Noldorin Wow it seems `titlesec` is making it intentionally hard to make such a patch... see my edit.

Comment: Yeah, that works nicely now! This is all rather magical to me, so I believe you when you say *titlesec* made the job rather hard. Many thanks for the solution, in any case. :)