# Mark a place "to be done" with todonotes

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, sectioning, todonotes

I'm trying to create a `\tbd` (To Be Done) macro to add a todonote on a chapter/section/subsection/etc easily with the following properties.

- to have a useful list of todos with a simple macro call: the todolist entry should represent the place of the todo inside the structure of the document (in the chapter named "C" it should have "TBD: C", in section "S" inside "C" it should have "TBD: C/S")
- to avoid redundancy: I don't want to type the section title as a caption parameter each and every time. What if I want to change the title?
- to display TBD in the note only (this seems to be more elegant)
- preferred: keep the name of the command as `\section` (and others) (with the use of an optional argument maybe?)
- preferred (but seems to be unlikely): without messing with the definition of `section` and friends
- preferred (but seems to be really messy): with the todonote "pointing" at the title

*Note: I've considered the possibility to put `\tbd` inside the section command (`\section{title\tbd}`) for the `todonote` to point at the right place, but this seems to be more pain than gain. Especially if I want to use the title...*

Something like this (the blue bordered things are on different pages):

[image]

Is there a macro/package for this or does any of you have a similar implementation?

Example is shown using a half (or less) solution. Can I list the current stack of chapter/section/etc somehow?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\newcommand\treeloc{dummy} % this should be replaced

\newcommand\tbd{\todo[caption={TBD: \treeloc}]{TBD}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{C-1}

\section{S-1}\tbd

\section{S-2}

\chapter{C-2}\tbd

\section{S-1}

\section{S-2}

\subsection{SS-1}\tbd

\section{S-3}

\listoftodos

\end{document}
```

And `\treeloc` should be changed for the todolist to have these instead of dummies:

- C-1/S-1
- C-2
- C-2/S-2/SS-1

I'm going to work on this, but I thought this was a nice question.

References (I'm considering to use):

- [An answer on: how to get the current chapter name, section name, subsection name, etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62252/36821)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142242/robust-way-to-mark-draft-text/142258#142258

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: already gave it a (+1), but thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[THIS IS NOT WHAT YOU WANT, IS IT?]

This does it by parsing `\thesubsection`, and printing something out if the respective units are not equal to `0`.  The relevant routines are `\getss` and `\gets`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\getss#1.#2|{\expandafter\gets#1|\ifstrequal{#2}{0}{}{/SS-#2}}
\def\gets#1.#2|{C-#1\ifstrequal{#2}{0}{}{/S-#2}}
\newcommand\treeloc{\expandafter\getss\thesubsection|}
\makeatother
\newcommand\tbd{\todo[caption={TBD: \treeloc}]{TBD}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{C-1}

\section{S-1}\tbd

\section{S-2}

\chapter{C-2}\tbd

\section{S-1}

\section{S-2}

\subsection{SS-1}\tbd

\section{S-3}

\listoftodos

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Update: I've tested this poorly. I wanted titles in the `treeloc` text instead of C-0 and C-1 independently from titles. I will submit my edited version as an answer soon.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution which fits my specification better:

[image]

```
\documentclass[openany,14pt]{book}

\usepackage[a5paper,margin=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm,marginparwidth=1.6cm,marginparsep=0.2cm]{geometry} % for demo only

\usepackage[textwidth=1.6cm]{todonotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\def\resetnamelevel#1{%
    \ifnum#1<1\let\thischaptername\relax\fi
    \ifnum#1<2\let\thissectionname\relax\fi
    \ifnum#1<3\let\thissubsectionname\relax\fi
    \ifnum#1<4\let\thissubsubsectionname\relax\fi
}\resetnamelevel{0}

\def\chaptername#1{\resetnamelevel{0}\def\thischaptername{#1}}
\def\sectionname#1{\resetnamelevel{1}\def\thissectionname{#1}}
\def\subsectionname#1{\resetnamelevel{2}\def\thissubsectionname{#1}}
\def\subsubsectionname#1{\resetnamelevel{3}\def\thissubsubsectionname{#1}}

\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark
\let\Subsubsectionmark\subsubsectionmark
\def\chaptermark#1{\chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}
\def\sectionmark#1{\sectionname{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}
\def\subsectionmark#1{\subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}
\def\subsubsectionmark#1{\subsubsectionname{#1}\Subsubsectionmark{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\treeloc{%
    \ifx\thischaptername\relax%
        ??\@latex@warning{\textbackslash treeloc called outside of structure}
    \else
        \thischaptername%
        \ifx\thissectionname\relax%
        \else
            \ /\ \thissectionname%
            \ifx\thissubsectionname\relax%
            \else
                \ /\ \thissubsectionname%
                \ifx\thissubsubsectionname\relax%
                \else
                    \ /\ \thissubsubsectionname%
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
    }
\makeatother

\newcommand\tbd{%
    \todo[caption={TBD: \expandafter\treeloc}]{TBD}
}

\begin{document}

TREELOC: \treeloc

\chapter{Chapter one}\tbd
TREELOC: \treeloc

\section{Section one}\tbd
TREELOC: \treeloc

\subsection{Subsection one}\tbd
TREELOC: \treeloc

\subsubsection{Subsubsection one}\tbd
TREELOC: \treeloc

\subsection{Subsection two}\tbd
TREELOC: \treeloc

%\chapter*{Not indexed chapter}\tbd
%TREELOC: \treeloc

%\chapter*{Unset chapter}\resetnamelevel{0}\tbd
%TREELOC: \treeloc

\chapter*{Manually named chapter}\chaptername{Manually named chapter}\tbd
TREELOC: \treeloc

\section*{Manually named section}\sectionname{Manually named section}\tbd
TREELOC: \treeloc

\listoftodos

\end{document}
```

If there's no chapter name set, then a warning is raised and `??` is displayed.

[image]