# How to get the current chapter* name, section* name, subsection* name, etc?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, cross-referencing

I came across [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62252/36821) which claims that it works even with the starred version of `\chapter` et al. The following example shows that it does not, because `\...mark` macros are not called. Is there a way to "fix" this and be able to set the respective value of the `\...name` macros even if there is a *-type call?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark
\let\Subsubsectionmark\subsubsectionmark
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}
\def\sectionmark#1{\def\Sectionname{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}
\def\subsubsectionmark#1{\def\Subsubsectionname{#1}\Subsubsectionmark{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
Title: ``\Chaptername''.
\section{First section}
Title: ``\Sectionname''.
\subsection{First subsection}
Title: ``\Subsectionname''.
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
Title: ``\Subsubsectionname''.
\chapter*{Second chapter}
Title: ``\Chaptername''.
\section*{Second section}
Title: ``\Sectionname''.
\subsection*{Second subsection}
Title: ``\Subsectionname''.
\subsubsection*{Second subsubsection}
Title: ``\Subsubsectionname''.
\end{document}
```

Lets assume that I have a long file with many `\section` (etc.) calls. But there is a macro which I want to change to contain the title of the actual `section` (etc.).

Comment: See package `nameref`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel doesn't the use of `nameref` mean that I have to `\label` each and every section, chapter, etc? If I want to automatize the labeling the problem seems to remain the same with a little more thinkering with labels.

Comment: No, it won't do what it's claimed, because `\...mark` is called only for the non *-version.

Comment: However, it's not very clear what you want to achieve: a `\chapter*` command doesn't set any label. So your `\chapter*{Second chapter}\label{ch:second}` will simply make `\ref{ch:second}` refer to `\subsubsection{First subsubsection}` (or the last refstepped counter at the same group level, in general).

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I've fixed my question. I was asking about a way to set the `\...name` macros even there is a * call.

Comment: I still don't understand what the use of this would be.

Comment: @egreg: To use [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142813/mark-a-place-to-be-done-with-todonotes) with section titles in the `todolist`. Maybe it would be better to unset them if a `\chapter*` macro call occurs (but this would only mean to set them to `\relax` instead of the title.

Comment: How many `\chapter*` do you have? I guess one or two: alternating numbered and unnumbered chapters (or sections or subsections) is quite dubious practice. So I continue not to understand what this would be for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The given macros will not work with the `*`-versions, because the `\...mark` commands are issued only when the `*` is not present. For instance, `\chapter{Title}` issues `\chaptermark{Title}`, but `\chapter*{Title}` doesn't.

Here's a set of patches that will provide the commands

```
\chaptertitle
\sectiontitle
\subsectiontitle
\subsubsectiontitle
```

which will always expand to the most recent title of the corresponding sectional unit.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% Patch the sectioning commands to provide a hook to be used later
\preto{\chapter}{\def\leveltitle{\chaptertitle}}
\preto{\section}{\def\leveltitle{\sectiontitle}}
\preto{\subsection}{\def\leveltitle{\subsectiontitle}}
\preto{\subsubsection}{\def\leveltitle{\subsubsectiontitle}}

\makeatletter
% \@sect is called with normal sectioning commands
% Argument #8 to \@sect is the title
% Thus \section{Title} will do \gdef\sectiontitle{Title}
\pretocmd{\@sect}
  {\expandafter\gdef\leveltitle{#8}}
  {}{}
% \@ssect is called with *-sectioning commands
% Argument #5 to \@ssect is the title
\pretocmd{\@ssect}
  {\expandafter\gdef\leveltitle{#5}}
  {}{}
% \@chapter is called by \chapter (without *)
% Argument #2 to \@chapter is the title
\pretocmd{\@chapter}
  {\expandafter\gdef\leveltitle{#2}}
  {}{}
% \@schapter is called with \chapter*
% Argument #1 to \@schapter is the title
\pretocmd{\@schapter}
  {\expandafter\gdef\leveltitle{#1}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\test{%
  \noindent
  The chapter title is \chaptertitle\\
  The section title is \sectiontitle\\
  The subsection title is \subsectiontitle\\
  The subsubsection title is \subsubsectiontitle
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\test

\chapter*{Second chapter}
\section*{Second section}
\subsection*{Second subsection}
\subsubsection*{Second subsubsection}

\test
\end{document}
```

Here `\test` is just to show that at the point the command is issued the control sequences hold the right value.

[image]

[image]

The patches must go before the loading of `hyperref` (if you use it).

Comment: +1, thanks, but your commented "answered" the question better :) (and I asked the question only because I found the referred answer mistaken)

Comment: @masu I added the reason why the macros you found don't work and also commented the code

Comment: I meant [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142982/how-to-get-the-current-chapter-name-section-name-subsection-name-etc?noredirect=1#comment323711_142982), but doesn't really matter. :)