# Accessing chapter's name in Koma-Script

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, koma-script

I looked up for a solution to access the name of current sections (chapters, sections, etc.) from macros (including starred variations of the section command). The set of macros proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/143003/179585) works like a charm in the base class `book`.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% Patch the sectioning commands to provide a hook to be used later
\preto{\chapter}{\def\leveltitle{\chaptertitle}}
\preto{\section}{\def\leveltitle{\sectiontitle}}
\preto{\subsection}{\def\leveltitle{\subsectiontitle}}
\preto{\subsubsection}{\def\leveltitle{\subsubsectiontitle}}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@sect}
  {\expandafter\gdef\leveltitle{#8}}
  {}{}
\pretocmd{\@ssect}
  {\expandafter\gdef\leveltitle{#5}}
  {}{}
\pretocmd{\@chapter}
  {\expandafter\gdef\leveltitle{#2}}
  {}{}
\pretocmd{\@schapter}
  {\expandafter\gdef\leveltitle{#1}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\test{%
  \noindent
  The chapter title is \chaptertitle\\
  The section title is \sectiontitle\\
  The subsection title is \subsectiontitle\\
  The subsubsection title is \subsubsectiontitle
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\test

\chapter*{Second chapter}
\section*{Second section}
\subsection*{Second subsection}
\subsubsection*{Second subsubsection}

\test
\end{document}
```

[image: book_example]

However I need to implement my macros in Koma-Script, with `scrbook` and here things start to get unexpected. With the same code but with class `scrbook` I get the following:

[image]

The chapter name is not rendered. I looked up the code of `scrbook` and the title is indeed #2. Is there something wrong with the macros and how to fix this issue?

For my needs, it is not possible to use `nameref`, I need a hard-coded solution. Thanks for you help.

Bonus: Is it possible to choose between long titles and short titles (the ones defined with `\section[short]{long}`? Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `nameref`, all you need is an automatically set `\label` and a the name of the current label. From upcomming KOMA-Script 3.27 (currently only available from the KOMA-Script source repository or the [KOMA-Script pre-release repository](https://komascript.de/node/1801)) the new do-hook feature can be used to add the automatic labels:

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}[2019/03/05]
\usepackage{nameref}
\newcounter{secautolabel}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup}{\setautolabel}
\newcommand*{\setautolabel}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{secautolabel}%
  \label{sec:autolabel:\thesecautolabel}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname #1title\endcsname{%
    \noexpand\nameref{sec:autolabel:\thesecautolabel}%
  }%
}

\newcommand\test{%
  \noindent
  The chapter title is \chaptertitle\\
  The section title is \sectiontitle\\
  The subsection title is \subsectiontitle\\
  The subsubsection title is \subsubsectiontitle
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection[reference={The First subsection reference}]{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\test

\chapter*{Second chapter}
\section*{Second section}
\subsection*{Second subsection}
\subsubsection*{Second subsubsection}

\test
\end{document}
```

with the results:

[image: numbered headings]
[image: not numbered headings]

So you do not need to patch or use (internal) commands.

With the current official release you can do something similar by patching `\sectionlinesformat` and `\chapterlinesformat`:

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{nameref}
\newcounter{secautolabel}
\newcommand*{\setautolabel}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{secautolabel}%
  \label{sec:autolabel:\thesecautolabel}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname #1title\endcsname{%
    \noexpand\nameref{sec:autolabel:\thesecautolabel}%
  }%
}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\sectionlinesformat}{\setautolabel{#1}}{}{\undefined}
\xapptocmd{\sectioncatchphraseformat}{\setautolabel{#1}}{}{\undefined}
\xapptocmd{\chapterlinesformat}{\setautolabel{#1}}{}{\undefined}
\xapptocmd{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}{\setautolabel{#1}}{}{\undefined}

\newcommand\test{%
  \noindent
  The chapter title is \chaptertitle\\
  The section title is \sectiontitle\\
  The subsection title is \subsectiontitle\\
  The subsubsection title is \subsubsectiontitle
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection[reference={The First subsection reference}]{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\test

\chapter*{Second chapter}
\section*{Second section}
\subsection*{Second subsection}
\subsubsection*{Second subsubsection}

\test
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

BTW: In both examples I've shown, how to manipulate the result using option `headings=optiontotocandhead` and the extended optional argument of, e.g., `\subsection`.

Comment: Thank you, neat solutions! I went with the second one as I want to stay with current official release of KOMA-Script. One more clarification: is it possible to have the same result with ``\part``section command? I tried to find similar hooks for ``part``without success.

Comment: @81737 Please have a look into the KOMA-Script manual. Immediately before the description of `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` and `\chapterlinesformat` you can find `\partlineswithprefixformat`. And the suggestion for KOMA-Script 3.27 using do-hooks should work for parts too. If not, it is not yet implemented.