# Accessing Chapter Titles for Use in LOF - classicthesis

Tags: pdftex, chapters, tocloft, classicthesis

I have been heavily reliant on Tex Stack in customising the classicthesis style. I am trying to segregate the list of figures page by splitting the figures into chapters. I tried to extract the chapter title by:

```
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}
\preto\figure{%
  \ifnum\value{figure}=0\addtocontents{lof}{{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\thechapter \quad \Chaptername} \vskip10pt}}\fi
}
```

However, I would like to extract or access the long chapter title instead of `\chaptermark`. I have tried the following patches but without any success.

[How to get the current chapter* name, section* name, subsection* name, etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142982/how-to-get-the-current-chapter-name-section-name-subsection-name-etc)

[Accessing chapter's name in Koma-Script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485065/accessing-chapters-name-in-koma-script)

[how to get the current chapter name, section name, subsection name, etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62241/how-to-get-the-current-chapter-name-section-name-subsection-name-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: How about this solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398166/

Comment: This solution also uses the ```\chaptermark```. Since I define chapter as
```\chapter[toc title]{title}
\chaptermark[head title]```

I want to use the title and not the head title as headings to the list of figures. I am not sure how to access this part using a variable

Comment: I don't see `\chaptermark` in Werner's solution, hm...

Comment: I think his solution is building on the original question. ```\thechaptername``` is defined using ```\chaptermark```.

Comment: I believe it's the `\@chapter` command (in most classes) that ''eats'' the two arguments - short and long title - so you could just patch it to save the long title for you. Check for example report.cls (or standardsections.hak if using koma-script). Other than that, you could make your own `\mychapter` command that would wrap the existing one: save arg #2 in `\mylongtitle`, then call `\chapter`.