# Re-use chapter and section titles in an introductory section on the thesis' structure?

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to re-use the titles of chapters and sections in a section on the structure of my thesis. How can I accomplish inclusion of the section heading, as it is for example used in the table of contents, in such a chapter?

A MWE illustrating my intentions goes as  follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Coarse Overview}
\subsection{Structure}

In Section~\ref{sec:related_work} we talk about XXXX % XXXX should actually be "Related Work".
In Section~\ref{sec:model} we talk about XXXX % XXXX should actually be "Model".
In Section~\ref{sec:evaluation} we talk about XXXX % XXXX should actually be "Evaluation".
In Section~\ref{sec:conclusion} we conclude.

\section{Related Work}
\label{sec:related_work}
\section{Model}
\label{sec:model}
\section{Evaluation}
\label{sec:evaluation}
\section{Conclusion}
\label{sec:conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) package, as suggested in [How to get the current chapter name, section name, subsection name, etc?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62241/5764)

Comment: Thank you, @Werner. This was exactly what I was looking for.