# Replacing \fancyhdr with \titlesec in complicated design documents

Tags: fancyhdr, titlesec

Thes page on the picture below (from [this](http://latex-my.blogspot.jp/search/label/bookdesign) post) has been created within `\fancyhdr` package, but I need to something like this keeping incompatible `\titlesec` usage and using **twopage** layout.

[image]

Really, I have no idea how to use tikz codes with `\titlesec` interface, but to save your time, I prepared the draft. It's no much, but...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{% Please make twoside settings 
   paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm,
   bindingoffset=0mm, asymmetric,
   left=13mm,  %% or inner=23mm
   right=18mm, %% or outer=18mm
   top=11mm, bottom=11mm,
   headsep=3mm,
   footskip=3mm
}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}

\newpagestyle{redfancy}[]{% Please insert the settings}
\newpagestyle{bluefancy}[]{% Please insert the settings}

\begin{document}

% 1st red page
\pagestyle{redfancy} % color: Header/Footer/Margin color: Firebrick2
\sethead[][][\thesection\quad\sectiontitle]{\thesection\quad\sectiontitle}{}{}
\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}

\section{First Red section}
\subsection{Red A}
\subsubsection{Red AA}
\subsubsection{Red AB}

\newpage
% 2nd red page
\section{Second Red section}
\subsection{Red B}
\subsubsection{Red BA}
\subsubsection{Red BB}


\newpage % Blue page
\pagestyle{bluefancy} % color: Header/Footer/Margin color: DodgerBlue1
\section{Blue section}

\end{document}
```

Here is the sketch of desired result:

[image]

---

### Update

According the requests of the people who nicely managed to answer this question, I'll explain what I need from `titlesec` packgage.

First is the dynamical design. During TOC, intro, outro I need the more simple design, and then - fancy color design (Red page, Blue page etc).

[image]

Before, I did it this way:

```
%\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{tocandintro}[]{\headrule\setheadrule{0.5mm}\footrule\setfootrule{0.5mm}}

\pagestyle{tocandintro}
\sethead[Table of contents][][]{}{Table of contents}{\textsf{目次}}
\setfoot[\thepage][][ABC Project]{ABC Project}{}{\thepage}

\tableofcontents

\sethead[Intro][][]{}{}{Intro}
\setfoot[\thepage][][ABC Project]{ABC Project}{}{\thepage}
<Intro text>
\pagestyle{fancy} % And after - color fancy design
```

Then, I need dynamical color titles, as shown on the picture below.

[image]

Before, I did it this way:

```
% --- Section
\colorlet{SectionFrameColor}{blue!50}
\colorlet{SectionFillColor}{blue!20}
\colorlet{SectionFontColor}{blue!80}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\sffamily\color{SectionFontColor}}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)}]
\node[thick,draw=SectionFrameColor,fill=SectionFillColor,rectangle,rounded corners,text=white] {\thesection};
\end{tikzpicture}}{12pt}{}%
[{\titlerule[1pt]}]

\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]
% And than re-define section color...
```

As you see, besides decorative needs I want to change the **\paragraph** format.

Comment: Please, could you post the code used in fancyhdr?

Comment: I am very sorry, besides fancy header, footer and margin I need 'titlesec' for other needs, too (for example, for titles design). Also, there is already exist the solution with 'fancyhdr' (check link in the question field), so if don't use 'titlesec', there is no reason to post current question.

Comment: Does the configuration you posted not work with my solution?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to combine the new code you posted with the code in my solution. There is nothing new here: I've just demonstrated that it works so far as I can tell. (That is, so far as I understand your updated question.)

Comment: OK, I think it's enough. Please accept the 100 reputation as reward. @Peter Grill, I'm sorry, you've done the great work too, but because of the forum rules I can to give the reputation reward only to one person. All what I can do for you is push **This answer is useful** near your answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to tweak this and I don't recommend it because I think the use of `titlesec` is going to cause more trouble than it is worth. However, if you insist:

## Step 1: Initial Solution

This solution uses `tikzpagenodes` together with the `background` package. This leaves the page style commands from `titlesec` to just handle the content of the header. The page frame and footer content is constructed using TiKZ on the background of the page. The `even odd rule` ensures that only the outside of the frame is filled with colour and that a 'hole' is created to contain the page content.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}% you need this before tikz to avoid an option clash
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{% Please make twoside settings
  paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm,
  bindingoffset=0mm, asymmetric,
  left=13mm,  %% or inner=23mm
  right=18mm, %% or outer=18mm
  top=11mm, bottom=11mm,
  headsep=3mm,
  footskip=3mm
}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{background}
\newcommand{\colourframe}[2][white]{%
  \clearpage
  \backgroundsetup{%
    angle=0,
    scale=1,
    opacity=1,
    contents={%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \path [fill=#2, even odd rule]
          (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east)
          (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east)
          ;
        \node [fill=#1, draw=black, anchor=north, text=black, inner xsep=5mm, inner ysep=1.5mm, yshift=-1.5mm] at (current page text area.south) {\thepage};
      \end{tikzpicture}},
    position=current page.south west,
    nodeanchor=south west
  }%
  \pagestyle{colourfancy}%
  \sethead[][][\thesection\quad\sectiontitle]{\thesection\quad\sectiontitle}{}{}}

\newpagestyle{colourfancy}[]{}

\begin{document}

  \colourframe[orange]{red}
  \section{First Red section}
  \subsection{Red A}
  \subsubsection{Red AA}
  \subsubsection{Red AB}

  \newpage
  % 2nd red page
  \section{Second Red section}
  \subsection{Red B}
  \subsubsection{Red BA}
  \subsubsection{Red BB}

  \colourframe[cyan]{blue}
  \section{Blue section}

\end{document}
```

[image: red and blue frames]

Note that I'm unsure why you say you want two-sided settings when you do not seem to really be using them! That is, you have set things up so that the margins are the same on every page. That means the outer margin will sometimes be larger than the inner one and sometimes smaller.

## Step 2: Adjusting the Inner and Outer Margins

In your sketch, however, the output is closer to this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

...

\geometry{% Please make twoside settings
  paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm,
  bindingoffset=0mm,
  right=13mm,  %% or inner=23mm
  left=18mm, %% or outer=18mm
  top=11mm, bottom=11mm,
  headsep=3mm,
  footskip=3mm
}
```

[image: larger inner and smaller outer margins]

That makes the large margins on the inside and the small on the outside. A more usual layout would reverse that behaviour:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

...

\geometry{% Please make twoside settings
  paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm,
  bindingoffset=0mm,
  left=13mm,  %% or inner=23mm
  right=18mm, %% or outer=18mm
  top=11mm, bottom=11mm,
  headsep=3mm,
  footskip=3mm
}
```

[image: larger outer and smaller inner margins]

so that the larger margin is on the outside and the two smaller inner margins combine on a double-page spread.

## Step 3: Shrink the Frame

The code above does not allow the page itself any 'breathing' room. That is, the content is right bang up against the frame. This is non-optimal. It would be better to shrink the frame a little away from the contents of the page. This can be done using the `calc` library:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}% you need this before tikz to avoid an option clash
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{% Please make twoside settings
  bindingoffset=0mm,
  left=13mm,  %% or inner=23mm
  right=18mm, %% or outer=18mm
  top=11mm, bottom=11mm,
  headsep=3mm,
  footskip=3mm
}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{background}
\newcommand{\colourframe}[2][white]{%
  \clearpage
  \backgroundsetup{%
    angle=0,
    scale=1,
    opacity=1,
    contents={%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \path [fill=#2, even odd rule]
          (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east)
          ($(current page text area.south west) - (2mm,2mm)$) rectangle ($(current page text area.north east) + (2mm,2mm)$)
          ;
        \node [fill=#1, draw=black, anchor=north, text=black, inner xsep=5mm, inner ysep=1.5mm, yshift=-1mm] at ($(current page text area.south) - (0,2mm)$) {\thepage};
      \end{tikzpicture}},
    position=current page.south west,
    nodeanchor=south west
  }%
  \pagestyle{colourfancy}%
  \sethead[][][\thesection\quad\sectiontitle]{\thesection\quad\sectiontitle}{}{}}

\newpagestyle{colourfancy}[]{}

\begin{document}

  \colourframe[orange]{red}
  \section{First Red section}
  \subsection{Red A}
  \subsubsection{Red AA}
  \subsubsection{Red AB}

  \newpage
  % 2nd red page
  \section{Second Red section}
  \subsection{Red B}
  \subsubsection{Red BA}
  \subsubsection{Red BB}

  \colourframe[cyan]{blue}
  \section{Blue section}

\end{document}
```

I've specified 2mm of shrinkage but you can adjust this as you wish. Personally, I would increase the margin sizes somewhat - I think things look much too squeezed, especially since information has to be included within this space. But if you are short of paper, this does seem to work.

Here's the resulting double-page spread (i.e. pages 2 and 3):

[image: shrunken frame]

## Step 4: Incorporate Code from Updated Question

This is the result of incorporating the additional customisation you added to your question:

[image: custom layout with smaller inner margins]

I've adapted `\colourframe[]{}` so that it also configures the changes to the format for section titles, paragraph layout, headers and footers as shown in your example. The colour of the section titles etc. is based on the colour specified for the frame. As before, the optional argument specifies the background colour for the box containing the page number.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}% you need this before tikz to avoid an option clash
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{% Please make twoside settings
  bindingoffset=0mm,
  left=13mm,  %% or inner=23mm
  right=18mm, %% or outer=18mm
  top=11mm, bottom=11mm,
  headsep=3mm,
  footskip=3mm
}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{background}
\newcommand{\colourframe}[2][white]{%
  \clearpage
  \backgroundsetup{%
    angle=0,
    scale=1,
    opacity=1,
    contents={%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \path [fill=#2, even odd rule]
          (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east)
          ($(current page text area.south west) - (2mm,2mm)$) rectangle ($(current page text area.north east) + (2mm,2mm)$)
          ;
        \node [fill=#1, draw=black, anchor=north, text=black, inner xsep=5mm, inner ysep=1.5mm, yshift=-1mm] at ($(current page text area.south) - (0,2mm)$) {\thepage};
      \end{tikzpicture}},
    position=current page.south west,
    nodeanchor=south west
  }%
  \pagestyle{colourfancy}%
  \sethead[][][\thesection\quad\sectiontitle]{\thesection\quad\sectiontitle}{}{}%
  \setfoot[][][]{}{}{}%
  \colorlet{SectionFrameColor}{#2!50}%
  \colorlet{SectionFillColor}{#2!20}%
  \colorlet{SectionFontColor}{#2!80}%
  \titleformat{\section}[hang]{%
    \Large\sffamily\color{SectionFontColor}%
  }{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [
        baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)},
      ]
      \node [thick, draw=SectionFrameColor, fill=SectionFillColor, rectangle, rounded corners, text=white] {\thesection};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }{12pt}{}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]%
  \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]}

\newpagestyle{colourfancy}[]{}
\newpagestyle{tocandintro}[]{\headrule\setheadrule{0.5mm}\footrule\setfootrule{0.5mm}}
\backgroundsetup{%
  contents={},
}

\begin{document}

  \pagestyle{tocandintro}
  \sethead[Table of contents][][]{}{Table of contents}{\textsf{目次}}
  \setfoot[\thepage][][ABC Project]{ABC Project}{}{\thepage}

  \tableofcontents

  \clearpage% uncomment if you don't want to have Intro in the header of the final contents page
  \sethead[Intro][][]{}{}{Intro}
  Intro text

  \colourframe[orange]{red}
  \section{First Red section}
  \subsection{Red A}
  \subsubsection{Red AA}
  \subsubsection{Red AB}

  \newpage
  % 2nd red page
  \section{Second Red section}
  \subsection{Red B}
  \subsubsection{Red BA}
  \subsubsection{Red BB}

  \colourframe[cyan]{blue}
  \section{Blue section}

\end{document}
```

Adding `asymmetric` back into the page layout for `geometry`:

[image: custom layout with asymmetric margins]

Note that the margins are very like those you would get if using `oneside` in this case i.e. the margins are defined for left and right *as opposed to* inner and outer.

If you just want the larger margin on the inside, switch the values for the left and right margin *rather than* passing `asymmetric`. This gives you:

[image: custom layout with larger inner margins]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a preliminary version (might need some tweaking upon further testing):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{background}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{% Please make twoside settings 
   paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm,
   bindingoffset=0mm, asymmetric,
   inner=23mm,  %% or inner=23mm
   outer=18mm, %% or outer=18mm
   top=11mm, 
   bottom=11mm,
   headsep=3mm,
   footskip=3mm,
%   showframe,
}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
%\usepackage{showframe} 


\usepackage{changepage}
\strictpagecheck

\newcommand*{\HeaderIndent}{2.0cm}%
\newlength{\MinimumPageNodeHeight}
\setlength{\MinimumPageNodeHeight}{3.0ex}

\newcommand*{\HeaderXLocation}{\dimexpr1.0in+\hoffset+\HeaderIndent\relax}%
\newcommand*{\HeaderYLocation}{\dimexpr1.0in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight\relax}%
\newcommand*{\FooterXLocation}{\dimexpr1.0in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+0.5\textwidth\relax}%
\newcommand*{\FooterYLocation}{\dimexpr1.0in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight+\footskip\relax}%

\newcommand*{\VOffsetTop}{\HeaderYLocation-\headsep}% 
\newcommand*{\VLocationBottom}{\dimexpr1.0in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight+\footskip}% vertical offset
\newcommand*{\VOffsetBottom}{\dimexpr\paperheight-\VLocationBottom-0.5\MinimumPageNodeHeight\relax}% vertical offset
\newcommand*{\HOffsetInner}{\dimexpr1.0in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin}% horizontal offset
\newcommand*{\HOffsetOuter}{\dimexpr1.0in+\hoffset+\evensidemargin}% horizontal offset

\newcommand*{\PageBorderFillColor}{}%
\newcommand*{\PageNumberFillColor}{}%

\newcommand*{\SetPageStyle}[2]{%
    \xdef\PageBorderFillColor{#1}%
    \xdef\PageNumberFillColor{#2}%
}%


%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62241/how-to-get-the-current-chapter-name-section-name-subsection-name-etc
\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark
\def\sectionmark#1{\def\CurrentSectionName{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}


\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\MyTikzLogo}{% For a logo drawn with TikZ
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,draw=black,ultra thick]
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
    \fill [\PageBorderFillColor] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\HOffsetInner,\paperheight);
    \fill [\PageBorderFillColor] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,\VOffsetBottom);
    \fill [\PageBorderFillColor] (current page.south east) rectangle ++(-\HOffsetOuter,\paperheight);
    \fill [\PageBorderFillColor] (current page.north east) rectangle ++(-\paperwidth,-\VOffsetTop);
    
    \coordinate (Title Location) at 
            ($(current page.north west)+(\HeaderXLocation,-\HeaderYLocation)+(\oddsidemargin,0)$);
    \coordinate (Page Number Location) at 
            ($(current page.north west)+(\FooterXLocation,-\FooterYLocation)$);
\else
    \fill [\PageBorderFillColor] (current page.south east) rectangle ++(-\HOffsetInner,\paperheight);
    \fill [\PageBorderFillColor] (current page.south east) rectangle ++(-\paperwidth,\VOffsetBottom);
    \fill [\PageBorderFillColor] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\HOffsetOuter,\paperheight);
    \fill [\PageBorderFillColor] (current page.north east) rectangle ++(-\paperwidth,-\VOffsetTop);
    
    \coordinate (Title Location) at 
            ($(current page.north west)+(\dimexpr\HeaderXLocation,-\HeaderYLocation)+(\evensidemargin,0)+(\marginparsep,0)$);
    \coordinate (Page Number Location) at 
            ($(current page.north east)+(-\FooterXLocation,-\FooterYLocation)$);
\fi

\node [draw=none, fill=none, anchor=south west, text=black, font=\bfseries]
        at (Title Location) {\HeaderTitle};
\node [
        draw=black, 
        fill=\PageNumberFillColor, 
        minimum width=1.5cm, 
        minimum height=\MinimumPageNodeHeight, 
        anchor=center, 
        text=black
    ] at (Page Number Location) {\thepage};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand*{\HeaderTitle}{\thesection\ \CurrentSectionName}

\SetBgContents{\MyTikzLogo}% Set tikz picture

\SetBgPosition{current page.north west}% Select location
\SetBgOpacity{1.0}% Select opacity
\SetBgAngle{0.0}% Select roation of logo
\SetBgScale{1.0}% Select scale factor of logo


\begin{document}
\SetPageStyle{red!75}{orange}
\section{First Red section}
\subsection{Red A}
\subsubsection{Red AA}
\subsubsection{Red AB}

\newpage
% 2nd red page
\section{Second Red section}
\subsection{Red B}
\subsubsection{Red BA}
\subsubsection{Red BB}


\newpage % Blue page
\SetPageStyle{blue!50}{teal}
\section{Blue section}

\newpage % Green page
\SetPageStyle{green!50}{magenta}
\section{Green section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but is your solution compatible with `titlesec` package? It's OK to don't use its commands for page design, but i need to hold `\usepackage{titlesec}` in my preamble.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu: Can you provide a list of customizations you need via `titlesec`? The current solution was meant to produce the sketch of the desires results given in the MWE.

Comment: First, it's a header/footer contents which could be changed with layout (For example 'table of contents', 'intro', 'part 1' etc.). Second, it's a part/section/subsection/paragraph titles control (as in [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207439/tikztitlesec-complicated-part-design) question).

Comment: @GurebuBokofu The header and footer contents change by default in that way, don't they? That is, they are sensitive to various aspects of the current context (and can be customised independently of `titlesec`). I generally find that whatever I think `titlesec` would be useful for is more easily done by dispensing with it. But I admit others seem to find it works better than I do.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu You said you'd no idea how to use TiKZ with `titlesec` but doesn't the question you linked to do precisely that?

Comment: @Peter Grill, in the current question, problem is color page outline. In the question about titles, TikZ used for titles setting. Verrym sorry, I'd better to say before 'have no idea how to use TikZ with titlesec for page color outlite', which must be more exactly.

Comment: @cfr, OK, what about titles design settiong without titlesec? Is the titlesec is most powerful package for targets like this?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu: I guess I am not fully understanding you. The question you link will adjust the titles based on you starting a new `\part`. Similarly this solution will adapt upon new `\section{}`, which is what the MWE above showed. If you want these to adjust based on `\part`, `\chapter` etc. that can be done.  So, if you edit the question with actual examples of the desires results along with the desired `titlesec` usage I can look into this further.

Comment: OK, I edited the question field; please check it after **Update**.