# Complicated design with bxjsarticle class

Tags: header-footer

This question is extention for other my question [Replacing \fancyhdr with \titlesec in complicated design documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207292/replacing-fancyhdr-with-titlesec-in-complicated-design-documents).

Really, I work with Japanese and according [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/how-to-write-japanese-with-latex) advice, for me **XeLaTeX** with **bxjsclasses** is optimal. When I have try the solution from prevous answer, I got output represented on the picture below.

[image]

The `geometry` package settings must define same parameters, as before, but frame position is invalid with **bxjsarticle**.

First, just for test you may compile below MWE with PDFLaTeX. When test with XeLaTeX, replace `\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}` with `\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{bxjsarticle}`. If you have not got this class, you can obtain it [here](https://github.com/zr-tex8r/BXjscls).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}% you need this before tikz to avoid an option clash
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{% Please make twoside settings
  bindingoffset=0mm,
  left=13mm,  %% or inner=23mm
  right=18mm, %% or outer=18mm
  top=11mm, bottom=11mm,
  headsep=3mm,
  footskip=3mm
}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{background}
\newcommand{\colourframe}[2][white]{%
  \clearpage
  \backgroundsetup{%
    angle=0,
    scale=1,
    opacity=1,
    contents={%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \path [fill=#2, even odd rule]
          (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east)
          ($(current page text area.south west) - (2mm,2mm)$) rectangle ($(current page text area.north east) + (2mm,2mm)$)
          ;
        \node [fill=#1, draw=black, anchor=north, text=black, inner xsep=5mm, inner ysep=1.5mm, yshift=-1mm] at ($(current page text area.south) - (0,2mm)$) {\thepage};
      \end{tikzpicture}},
    position=current page.south west,
    nodeanchor=south west
  }%
  \pagestyle{colourfancy}%
  \sethead[][][\thesection\quad\sectiontitle]{\thesection\quad\sectiontitle}{}{}%
  \setfoot[][][]{}{}{}%
  \colorlet{SectionFrameColor}{#2!50}%
  \colorlet{SectionFillColor}{#2!20}%
  \colorlet{SectionFontColor}{#2!80}%
  \titleformat{\section}[hang]{%
    \Large\sffamily\color{SectionFontColor}%
  }{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [
        baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)},
      ]
      \node [thick, draw=SectionFrameColor, fill=SectionFillColor, rectangle, rounded corners, text=white] {\thesection};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }{12pt}{}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]%
  \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]}

\newpagestyle{colourfancy}[]{}
\newpagestyle{tocandintro}[]{\headrule\setheadrule{0.5mm}\footrule\setfootrule{0.5mm}}
\backgroundsetup{%
  contents={},
}

\begin{document}

  \pagestyle{tocandintro}
  \sethead[Table of contents][][]{}{Table of contents}{\textsf{Table of contents}}
  \setfoot[\thepage][][ABC Project]{ABC Project}{}{\thepage}

  \tableofcontents

  \clearpage% uncomment if you don't want to have Intro in the header of the final contents page
  \sethead[Intro][][]{}{}{Intro}
  Intro text

  \colourframe[orange]{red}
  \section{First Red section}
  \subsection{Red A}
  \subsubsection{Red AA}
  \subsubsection{Red AB}

  \newpage
  % 2nd red page
  \section{Second Red section}
  \subsection{Red B}
  \subsubsection{Red BA}
  \subsubsection{Red BB}

  \colourframe[cyan]{blue}
  \section{Blue section}

\end{document}
```

Please do not draw attention to strange TOC: I can repair it myself.

Comment: Do you mean the red rectangle's wrong placement? This need 2-3 compilations.

Comment: It's no use with XeLaTeX and **bxjsarticle** class: I tested.

Comment: Oh! Yes `xelatex` has some problems. Try `lualatex` instead. It works.

Comment: Heh... LuaLaTeX worked:) But let us keep this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have XeTeX, but the problem was reproduced with pLaTeX + dvipdfmx.
(I recommend (u)pLaTeX for Japanese typesetting because of its popularity, speed and quality.)

Removal of `\backgroundsetup`s solved the problem.
It seems that combination of `current page` in `{tikzpicture}` and position specification in `\backgroundsetup` is causing the unexpected behavior.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside, dvipdfmx]{jsarticle}

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}% you need this before tikz to avoid an option clash
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes,pxpgfmark}
% pxpgfmark for using remember picture with platex + dvipdfmx
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{% Please make twoside settings
  bindingoffset=0mm,
  left=13mm,  %% or inner=23mm
  right=18mm, %% or outer=18mm
  top=11mm, bottom=11mm,
  headsep=3mm,
  footskip=3mm
}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newcommand{\colourframe}[2][white]{%
  \clearpage
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \path [fill=#2, even odd rule]
          (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east)
          ($(current page text area.south west) - (2mm,2mm)$) rectangle ($(current page text area.north east) + (2mm,2mm)$)
          ;
        \node [fill=#1, draw=black, anchor=north, text=black, inner xsep=5mm, inner ysep=1.5mm, yshift=-1mm] at ($(current page text area.south) - (0,2mm)$) {\thepage};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
  \pagestyle{colourfancy}%
  \sethead[][][\thesection\quad\sectiontitle]{\thesection\quad\sectiontitle}{}{}%
  \setfoot[][][]{}{}{}%
  \colorlet{SectionFrameColor}{#2!50}%
  \colorlet{SectionFillColor}{#2!20}%
  \colorlet{SectionFontColor}{#2!80}%
  \titleformat{\section}[hang]{%
    \Large\sffamily\color{SectionFontColor}%
  }{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [
        baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)},
      ]
      \node [thick, draw=SectionFrameColor, fill=SectionFillColor, rectangle, rounded corners, text=white] {\thesection};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }{12pt}{}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]%
  \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]}

\newpagestyle{colourfancy}[]{}
\newpagestyle{tocandintro}[]{\headrule\setheadrule{0.5mm}\footrule\setfootrule{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

  \pagestyle{tocandintro}
  \sethead[Table of contents][][]{}{Table of contents}{\textsf{Table of contents}}
  \setfoot[\thepage][][ABC Project]{ABC Project}{}{\thepage}

  \tableofcontents

  \clearpage% uncomment if you don't want to have Intro in the header of the final contents page
  \sethead[Intro][][]{}{}{Intro}
  Intro text

  \colourframe[orange]{red}
  \section{First Red section}
  \subsection{Red A}
  \subsubsection{Red AA}
  \subsubsection{Red AB}

  \newpage
  % 2nd red page
  \section{Second Red section}
  \subsection{Red B}
  \subsubsection{Red BA}
  \subsubsection{Red BB}

  \colourframe[cyan]{blue}
  \section{Blue section}

\end{document}
```