# Background package - \NoBgThispage different output

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec, backgrounds

This question related with my oter two questions:

- [Replacing \fancyhdr with \titlesec in complicated design documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207292/replacing-fancyhdr-with-titlesec-in-complicated-design-documents)
- [White fields in ltjsarticle class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208401/white-fields-in-ltjsarticle-class)

The design, which has been reached in these questions, represented on the picture below.

[image]

Continue this research, I tried to switch off color fields temporarry (for fly title, for example, and similas needs). I was successfully did it first time by `\NoBgThispage` of `background` package command, but it was found out that in case of current doccument `\NoBgThispage` works correct just one time.

Compile the MWE with LuaLaTeX (3 times, as always) and look: in page 7, where is a fly title model, there is no the color frame, but it appears again on the next page.

In page 11, there is the fly title again, but after that color frame in not appears.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}% you need this before tikz to avoid an option clash
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{calc}% based rather loosely on code from the introduction to the geometry manual
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth-31mm}% 13+18=31
\setlength\oddsidemargin{(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 - 1in - 2.5mm}% .5*(13-18)=-2.5
\setlength\evensidemargin{(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 - 1in + 2.5mm}% .5*(18-13)=2.5
\setlength\topmargin{11mm-1in}
\setlength\headsep{3mm}
\setlength\footskip{3mm}
\setlength\marginparwidth{0pt}
\setlength\marginparsep{0pt}
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight-\headheight-\headsep-\footskip-22mm}% 2*11=22

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{background}
\newcommand{\colourframe}[2][white]{%
  \clearpage
  \backgroundsetup{%
    angle=0,
    scale=1,
    opacity=1,
    contents={%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \path [fill=#2, even odd rule]
          (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east)
          ($(current page text area.south west) - (2mm,2mm)$) rectangle ($(current page text area.north east) + (2mm,2mm)$)
          ;
        \node [fill=#1, draw=black, anchor=north, text=black, inner xsep=5mm, inner ysep=1.5mm, yshift=-1mm] at ($(current page text area.south) - (0,2mm)$) {\thepage};
      \end{tikzpicture}},
    position=current page.south west,
    nodeanchor=south west
  }%
  \pagestyle{colourfancy}%
  \sethead[][][\thesection\quad\sectiontitle]{\thesection\quad\sectiontitle}{}{}%
  \setfoot[][][]{}{}{}%
  \colorlet{SectionFrameColor}{#2!50}%
  \colorlet{SectionFillColor}{#2!20}%
  \colorlet{SectionFontColor}{#2!80}%
  \titleformat{\section}[hang]{%
    \Large\sffamily\color{SectionFontColor}%
  }{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [
        baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)},
      ]
      \node [thick, draw=SectionFrameColor, fill=SectionFillColor, rectangle, rounded corners, text=white] {\thesection};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }{12pt}{}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]%
  \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]}

\newpagestyle{colourfancy}[]{}
\newpagestyle{tocandintro}[]{\headrule\setheadrule{0.5mm}\footrule\setfootrule{0.5mm}}
\backgroundsetup{%
  contents={},
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{tocandintro}
\sethead[Table of contents][][]{}{}{Table of contents}
\setfoot[\thepage][][ABC Project]{ABC Project}{}{\thepage}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage% uncomment if you don't want to have Intro in the header of the final contents page
\sethead[Intro][][]{}{}{Intro}
Intro text

\colourframe[orange]{red}
\part{RED}
\section{Red section}
\subsection{Red A}
\subsubsection{Red AA}

\lipsum{3-50}

\subsubsection{Red AB}

\lipsum{3-50}  

\subsection{Red B}
\subsubsection{Red BA}

\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\NoBgThispage
\part{BLUE}
\quad

\newpage\pagestyle{plain}
\colourframe[cyan]{blue}
\section{Blue section}
\subsubsection{Blue AA}

\lipsum{3-50}  
\subsubsection{Red AB}
\lipsum{3-50}  

\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\NoBgThispage
\part{GREEN}
\quad

\newpage\pagestyle{plain}
\colourframe[DarkSeaGreen1]{Green1}
\section{Green section}
\subsubsection{Blue AA}

\lipsum{3-50}  
\subsubsection{Red AB}
\lipsum{3-50}  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a work around. Define

```
\newcommand{\nocolourframe}{%
  \clearpage
  \backgroundsetup{%
    contents={}
    }
    \pagestyle{empty}
  }
```

and use it like

```
\cleardoublepage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\NoBgThispage
\nocolourframe
\part{GREEN}
\quad
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}% you need this before tikz to avoid an option clash
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{calc}% based rather loosely on code from the introduction to the geometry manual
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth-31mm}% 13+18=31
\setlength\oddsidemargin{(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 - 1in - 2.5mm}% .5*(13-18)=-2.5
\setlength\evensidemargin{(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 - 1in + 2.5mm}% .5*(18-13)=2.5
\setlength\topmargin{11mm-1in}
\setlength\headsep{3mm}
\setlength\footskip{3mm}
\setlength\marginparwidth{0pt}
\setlength\marginparsep{0pt}
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight-\headheight-\headsep-\footskip-22mm}% 2*11=22

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{background}
\newcommand{\colourframe}[2][white]{%
  \clearpage
  \backgroundsetup{%
    angle=0,
    scale=1,
    opacity=1,
    contents={%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \path [fill=#2, even odd rule]
          (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east)
          ($(current page text area.south west) - (2mm,2mm)$) rectangle ($(current page text area.north east) + (2mm,2mm)$)
          ;
        \node [fill=#1, draw=black, anchor=north, text=black, inner xsep=5mm, inner ysep=1.5mm, yshift=-1mm] at ($(current page text area.south) - (0,2mm)$) {\thepage};
      \end{tikzpicture}},
    position=current page.south west,
    nodeanchor=south west
  }%
  \pagestyle{colourfancy}%
  \sethead[][][\thesection\quad\sectiontitle]{\thesection\quad\sectiontitle}{}{}%
  \setfoot[][][]{}{}{}%
  \colorlet{SectionFrameColor}{#2!50}%
  \colorlet{SectionFillColor}{#2!20}%
  \colorlet{SectionFontColor}{#2!80}%
  \titleformat{\section}[hang]{%
    \Large\sffamily\color{SectionFontColor}%
  }{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [
        baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)},
      ]
      \node [thick, draw=SectionFrameColor, fill=SectionFillColor, rectangle, rounded corners, text=white] {\thesection};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }{12pt}{}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]%
  \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]}

\newcommand{\nocolourframe}{%
  \clearpage
  \backgroundsetup{%
    contents={}
    }
    \pagestyle{empty}
  }


\newpagestyle{colourfancy}[]{}
\newpagestyle{tocandintro}[]{\headrule\setheadrule{0.5mm}\footrule\setfootrule{0.5mm}}
\backgroundsetup{%
  contents={},
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{tocandintro}
\sethead[Table of contents][][]{}{}{Table of contents}
\setfoot[\thepage][][ABC Project]{ABC Project}{}{\thepage}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage% uncomment if you don't want to have Intro in the header of the final contents page
\sethead[Intro][][]{}{}{Intro}
Intro text

\colourframe[orange]{red}
\part{RED}
\section{Red section}
\subsection{Red A}
\subsubsection{Red AA}

\lipsum{3-50}

\subsubsection{Red AB}

\lipsum{3-50}

\subsection{Red B}
\subsubsection{Red BA}

\cleardoublepage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\nocolourframe
%\NoBgThispage
\part{BLUE}
\quad

\newpage\pagestyle{plain}
\colourframe[cyan]{blue}
\section{Blue section}
\subsubsection{Blue AA}

\lipsum{3-50}
\subsubsection{Red AB}
\lipsum{3-50}

\cleardoublepage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\NoBgThispage
\nocolourframe
\part{GREEN}
\quad

\newpage\pagestyle{plain}
\colourframe[DarkSeaGreen1]{Green1}
\section{Green section}
\subsubsection{Blue AA}

\lipsum{3-50}
\subsubsection{Red AB}
\lipsum{3-50}

\cleardoublepage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\NoBgThispage
\nocolourframe
\part{GREEN}
\quad

\newpage\pagestyle{plain}
\colourframe[olive]{brown}
\section{Green section}
\subsubsection{Blue AA}

\lipsum{3-50}
\subsubsection{Red AB}
\lipsum{3-50}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have used `article` class for obvious reasons.

Comment: It's OK, it works in my class, too. Thank you for quick answer!