# Background package - Troubles with `\NoBgThispage` command

Tags: backgrounds

I am not able to make this command be deterministic. The weird behaviour I get with PDFLaTeX is explained in the comments of the following MWE. I checked for conflicts with package `afterpage`, also maybe via `multicol`, in my original document and after reading the warning in `background`'s documentation, but it didn't help. What can I do?

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
\backgroundsetup{opacity=0.7,contents={\Huge MY BACKGROUND}}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}%  
%
\BgThispage{}\BgThispage{}\BgThispage{} %Shorthand to enhance opacity just here.

TITLE-PAGE


\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\NoBgThispage{} 


\thispagestyle{empty}
A first BgLess page.


\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}

%\NoBgThispage{} %THIS COMMAND WILL MAKE ALL THE FOLLOWING PAGES MISS THE BACKGROUND.

\textbf{No BG here, please, but yes afterwards. Shouldn't it be as easy as in the previous page?}


\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
%\BgThispage% Even this command will be bypassed.

\clearpage
%\NoBgThispage{} %Again, this will affect every remaining page.
TOC page.


\clearpage%

\lipsum[1-10]

\vfill{}Why is BG missing here?


\end{document}
```

Comment: well the implementation is faulty. If you issue `\NoBgThispage`  twice you loose the background.

Comment: I misunderstood your comment. I guess you mean the command itself is just a workaround to omit the background and it can only be used once in the whole document. Right? :(

Answer (score 0):

After @Ulrike Fischer's comment and this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210105/36389
a possible workaround for both enhancing opacity in specific pages and also omitting the background in others is to consider changing the background setup after `\begin{document}`. In this case, I defined 3 commands to hold different common setups along the document:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
\newcommand{\TitlePageBgOpacity}{0.95}
\newcommand{\NormalPageBgOpacity}{0.5}
\newcommand{\NoBgPageBgOpacity}{0}

\backgroundsetup{contents={\Huge MY BACKGROUND}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}%  
%
\backgroundsetup{opacity=\TitlePageBgOpacity}

TITLE-PAGE


\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\backgroundsetup{opacity=\NoBgPageBgOpacity}
\thispagestyle{empty}
A first BgLess page.


\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
%\backgroundsetup{opacity=\NoBgPageBgOpacity}

\textbf{No BG here, please, but yes afterwards. Shouldn't it be as easy as in the previous page?}


\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\backgroundsetup{opacity=\NormalPageBgOpacity}

\clearpage
\backgroundsetup{opacity=\NoBgPageBgOpacity}
TOC page.


\clearpage%
\backgroundsetup{opacity=\NormalPageBgOpacity}
\lipsum[1-10]

\vfill{}Why is BG missing here?


\end{document}
```