# access chapter or section title

Tags: macros, sectioning

Is there a base-LaTeX variable or macro by which one can access the title of a chapter or section?

The MWE below demonstrates a workaround, but it seems there might be a LaTeX variable or "command" already in existence?

The fact that LaTeX puts the chapter title into the header, suggests that this exists as a variable.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand{\nowtitle}{}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Stuff}

\verb!\theChapterTitle!  throws an error. 

\verb!\ChapterTitle!  throws an error.

\verb!\chaptertitle!  throws an error.

\verb!\today!
compiles as
\today

\verb!\thesection{}! compiles as \thesection{} 

\verb!\thechapter{}! compiles as \thechapter{}

\verb!\thepage{}! compiles as \thepage{} 

\verb!\nowtitle{}!  compiles as \nowtitle{}

\renewcommand{\nowtitle}{Lorem ipsum}\chapter{\nowtitle}

\verb!\nowtitle{}!  compiles as \nowtitle{}
\newpage One page 
\newpage
\verb!\nowtitle{}!  compiles as \nowtitle{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no base LaTeX macro holding the title of the `\chapter`. Let's see why by looking at a call to `\chapter{<title>}`. Here's the definition of `\chapter` inside [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) (similar inside [`report.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co)):

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

Note that `\chapter` doesn't take any argument. It merely conditions (via `\secdef`) on whether you called `\chapter` with/without a star `*`. If you called it `\chapter*`, it executes `\@schapter`, otherwise it executes `\@chapter`. Assuming you didn't use `\chapter*`, here's what `\@chapter` looks like:

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

Here argument `#1` is the *optional argument*, while argument `#2` is the *mandatory argument* you supplied as `<title>`. If you didn't supply the optional argument, this macro `\secdef` duplicates `#2` for `#1`, effectively calling `\chapter[<title>]{<title>}`. It's at this point where one can swoop in and grab either `#1` or `#2` as your `\nowtitle` using en [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\ifnum}% <search>
  {\edef\nowtitle{#1}\ifnum}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

As you should see from the definition of `\@chapter`, `#1` is used within `\chaptermark` and will therefore appear in the header, while `#2` is used within `\@makechapterhead` to set the chapter heading. I chose `#1` above, but you pick either (or store both).

`\chapter*` is a little different. A call to `\chapter*{<title>}` leads to calling `\@schapter`:

```
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
```

Here there is *no optional argument*, only the *mandatory* `{<title>}`. It suffices to patch `\@schapter` as follows:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@schapter}% <cmd>
  {\if@twocolumn}% <search>
  {\edef\nowtitle{#1}\if@twocolumn}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

Note that `\chapter*[<other>]{<stuff>}` is not allowed.

Here is a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\ifnum}% <search>
  {\edef\nowtitle{#1}\ifnum}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\@schapter}% <cmd>
  {\if@twocolumn}% <search>
  {\edef\nowtitle{#1}\if@twocolumn}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\newcommand{\nowtitle}{}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\chapter[Other]{Stuff}
% \chapter*{Stuff}

\verb!\nowtitle{}!: \nowtitle

\end{document}
```

It would also be possible to achieve the above patch *without* `etoolbox`, if needed. Also, a similar method can be used to store the title used for (sub)`\section`s:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
  {\ifnum}% <search>
  {\edef\nowtitle{#7}\ifnum}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\@ssect}% <cmd>
  {\@tempskipa}% <search>
  {\edef\nowtitle{#5}\@tempskipa}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

Argument `#7` and `#8` respectively point to (sub)`\section[<#7>]{<#8>}`.

---

It is often better using packages which provide similar functionality. For example, [`nameref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62242/5764) and [`titleref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202850/5764).

Answer (score 7):

You can hook into the mechanism which builds the header to save the chapter title.  You're right, it is already saved but not in an easily accessible manner.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand*\nowtitle{}

\let\oldchaptermark=\chaptermark
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{%
  \renewcommand*\nowtitle{#1}%
  \oldchaptermark{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Stuff}

\nowtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]