# Changing the default markup of fancyhdr headers

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to add a header to my pages and in doing so I ran into the problem of not being able to change the default markup of fancyhdr headers. More specifically, I want the header of every page to include the subsection and section without numberings and in regular text, so no italics or capitals.

The following MWE illustrates my problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

0

\subsection{Subsection}

1

\newpage

2

\end{document}
```

The first page's header does not show the title of the subsection,

[image: Header of the first page]

whereas the second page does.

[image: Header of the second page]

Both however have (sub)section numberings and sport markup. I would like them to look like this:

[image: Desired format]

I have tried renewing the appropriate commands which did not do me much good.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For your reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236715/121944

Comment: @AML Following that led me to a solution, thanks! I will post it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62241/how-to-get-the-current-chapter-name-section-name-subsection-name-etc/62252#62252) I solved the problem in this way:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark
\def\sectionmark#1{\def\Sectionname{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}
\let\Subsubsectionmark\subsubsectionmark
\def\subsubsectionmark#1{\def\Subsubsectionname{#1}\Subsubsectionmark{#1}}

\lhead{\Subsectionname}
\rhead{\Sectionname}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

0

\subsection{Subsection}

1

\newpage

2

\end{document}
```