# Store chapter name from unincluded part (potentially in part's aux file)

Tags: chapters, include, auxiliary-files

I use `\include` to insert parts into a large document. Some of the parts contain `chapter` declarations, others only sections. I would like to make the current chapter name available in the daughter sections, even when the `chapter` parts are unincluded.

My attempt was to modify the `\chaptermark` command (from the answer to [how to get the current chapter name, section name, subsection name, etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62241/how-to-get-the-current-chapter-name-section-name-subsection-name-etc)) to store the chapter name in `\@Chaptername` and also save this to the part's `aux` file.

However, my line in the `aux` file is written outside the `\@setckpt` such that all definitions of `\@Chaptername` are read in at the beginning of the document and the variable then holds the name of the last chapter (until an included `chapter` part overwrites it).

Here is a MNWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{filecontents}{Ch1.tex}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Ch2.tex}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\end{filecontents}

\includeonly{Ch2}       % <- Hide this to see the effect.

\makeatletter
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\def\chaptermark#1{\gdef\@Chaptername{\thechapter\enskip#1}\Chaptermark{#1}%
    \write\@partaux{\string\gdef\string\@Chaptername{\thechapter\enskip#1}}}
\def\Chaptername{\ifdefined\@Chaptername\@Chaptername\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\include{Ch1}

The parent chapter is called: \Chaptername

\include{Ch2}

\end{document}
```

With the marked line commented out, one gets the desired result:
[image]

With the marked line not commented out, one gets:
[image]

I suspect a possible solution could be to write to the checkpoint section `\@setckpt` in the part's `aux` file. Is this possible?

Or is there maybe a more elegant / better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you you use the same macro `\@Chaptername` for every chapter. So the "last value" of `\@Chaptername` is the one that gets used. This is OK when every chapter is included, since `\chaptermark` redefines it, but if a chapter is not included this becomes a problem. For your MWE the value of `\@Chaptername` is `2 Chapter 2`, which is not what you want.

To get around this you should define `\@Chaptername1`, `\@Chaptername2`, .... Unfortunately, (La)TeX is not fond of having numbers in macro names. You can get around this using `\csname ...\endcsname` but I prefer using `\csefd{...}` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) or, in this case `csgdef{...}`. With this slight modification in place your code works.

Here is the modified code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{filecontents}{Ch1.tex}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Ch2.tex}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\end{filecontents}

\includeonly{Ch2}       % <- Hide this to see the effect.

\makeatletter
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\def\chaptermark#1{%
  \csgdef{@Chaptername\arabic{chapter}}{\thechapter\enskip#1}\Chaptermark{#1}%
  \write\@partaux{\string\csgdef{@Chaptername\arabic{chapter}}{\thechapter\enskip#1}}%
}
\def\Chaptername{\ifcsdef{@Chaptername\arabic{chapter}}{\csuse{@Chaptername\arabic{chapter}}}{Chapter \arabic{chapter} unknown}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\include{Ch1}

The parent chapter is called: \Chaptername

\include{Ch2}

\end{document}
```