# Variables for book and chapter names

Tags: book-design

I am trying to configure a book using `fancyhdr`. I want the book name centred on even pages, and the chapter name centred on odd pages. That is all very well, except for two simple questions:

1. Is there a variable which stands for the book name?
2. Is there a variable which stands for the chapter name?

I may be stupid, but I can't seem to find the names of these obvious variables.

I could of course hardwire this in the preamble and at the
beginning of chapters, for my own variables, but this strikes me as a horrible kludge.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, but perhaps  [sectioning - how to get the current chapter name, section name, subsection name, etc? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62241/how-to-get-the-current-chapter-name-section-name-subsection-name-etc) is?

Comment: You probably want to place the book or chapter name in your header. You should have a look at how to set up the `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` macros (just search for these names on this site).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there is no variable that contains the book's title. You will have to create one yourself. I think that the MWE below gives you what I think you are after.

```
% titleprob.tex  SE 624386

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\textheight}{0.4\textheight}

\newcommand{\booktitle}{THE BOOK} % the title of the book
\usepackage{fancyhdr}             % your pagestyle
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[CE]{\booktitle}
\fancyhead[LE,RE]{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RO]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\title{\booktitle}
\author{A N Other}

\maketitle

 \chapter{Chapter}

Some text. the book's title is ``\booktitle''.
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

You might want to use different text for the actual title of the book and a another (shortened) version for the page headings.

Comment: I believe `\title{THE BOOK}` stores that in `\@title`.

Comment: But isn't that cleared after `\maketitle`?

Comment: @Teepeemm Ingmar is correct, also the author and date data are deleted. However the `memoir` class provides the `\thetitle`, `\theauthor` and `\thedate` which can be used after `\maketitle`.